# How to read and execute hql file(hive query) and create pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hql

I have a `.hql` file. I need to read and execute the query to create a dataframe from the query result.
I have the below code

```
def read_and_exec_hql(hql_file_path):
    with open(hql_file_path, 'r') as f:
        hql_query = f.read().strip()
    queries = [q.strip() for q in hql_query.splitlines() if q.strip() and not q.startswith('--')]
    df = None
    for query in queries:
        if df is None:
            df = spark.sql(query)
        else:
            df = df.union(spark.sql(query))
    return df
    
hql_file_path = 'path/to/hql/file'
df = read_and_exec_hql(hql_file_path)
df.show()
```

I'm getting `Py4JJavaError` for this.

Is there any other approach to read and execute hql files in pyspark.
Please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your full `Py4JJavaError` error and where do you get it?

Comment: `mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'('` getting this error message while calling the function

Comment: You can read hql file as is & split the queries based on `;` then pass each query to spark.sql(query) in loop. you don't have to delete comments because it should work same as hive in spark or any other meta info.